# Can't Create New Project in Eclipse for Android, after update android 4.1, why?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I don't understand why that happens, is not for me but my company staff member also face this problem.
[image]

I click on Install/Update , that update something but problem is not solved, I also check "Check Again" option. This problem I face after update android 4.1. before update it worked perfect.

Comment: What is the sdk location for android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uninstall the android support library from the android sdk manager first . then while creating project you will asked this pop up again click install/upgrade and it will work....

it's problem with 4.1 sdk. once you do above thing it will solve your problem.. same happen to me..

Comment: I think mods need the ability to accept in cases where the Op has done this.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem, try this.

Copy the contents from:

> D:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\compatibility

and create a new folder named **"support"** over here:

> D:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support

and paste the contents inside that, Now restart eclipse and try again!